# How can I get the mouse wheel to scroll through the contents of DBGridEh, and not record in it?

Tags: database

I know that this is what happens when MemTableEh is connected. But is it possible to do without connecting MemTableEh? I was told that if I use `DBGridEhCenter.TryUseViewScroll` - this should affect all DBGridEh used in the project, but I did not understand how it works

DBGridEhCenter.TryUseViewScroll := False; // I didn't see any effect

Comment: I have upvoted your question since you are new but stackoverflow is not meant to show you example code rather you are supposed to give  a non-working code in the question which others may help you debug. for software suggestion softwarerecs.stackexchange.com might suit better. Others are not as lenient as me and hence may close your question unless you edit it before they see it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm really a beginner. And my first steps are very problematic.

Comment: I figured it out and solved the problem by connecting MemTableEh. The issue has been resolved.

Comment: Great job, you should post your solution as answer. On stackoverflow you can answer you own questions too.